# Problems with GPU rendering in Ubuntu on a Macbook Pro Intel Iris 6100

Tags: gpu, linux, osx

So I know that it's impossible to use GPU on a Macbook Pro, running OSX, with Intel Graphic card in Blender 2.8 (I'm using 2.82). So I tried running Ubuntu on my Macbook with a USB booteable stick, blender works, but still says that Cycles will render from the CPU. So, is it possible to work? maybe it's because I'm running Ubuntu from a USB? Should I install something else?..thanks!

Macbook Pro 13 2015
Intel Iris Graphics 6100
OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Blender 2.82

Comment: is cuda driver /nvidida driver installed in ubuntu?.. can you try bootcamp windows10?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Intel's integrated GPUs don't fulfill the requirements [for GPU rendering in Blender 2.8x](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). You would either need a:

- Nvidia graphics card with CUDA compute capability 3.0 or higher
- AMD graphics card from [GCN second generation or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview)

> **CUDA**
>
> CUDA requires graphics cards with compute capability 3.0 and higher. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of Nvidia graphics cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with the compute capabilities and supported graphics cards. CUDA GPU rendering is supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

---

> **AMD**
>
> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. Blender supports graphics cards with GCN generation 2 and above. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of GCN generations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#Iterations) with the GCN generation and supported graphics cards.
>
> AMD OpenCL GPU rendering is supported on Windows and Linux, but not on macOS.

Comment: oh ok! so it's the same either Linux or OSX, the problem it's the graphic card..I thought it was the SO. well, problem "resolved" hah...thanks!